# setting up bios to recognise 2nd hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, bios

Hi there unfortunatly i had a problem this weekend with what i think is my graphics card failing, its an old machine so i dont see the point in replacing it, anyway i decided to rip out the HD and pop into another machine so i dont lose any info, im a web apps programmer and theres stuff on there that i am working on right now.

Anyway an ideal situation would be where i can boot from the 2nd drive in the new machine and carry on working on my project, however i feel that i may need to format this drive so that it can be recognised at a boot up and give me the option to boot from 1st or 2nd hard drive, is there any other way around formatting..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably recommend spending around £10-£15 on a second hand graphics card, or find one lying around (borrow/beg!) for your old machine and then running something such as [VMWare Converter](http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/), so you can virtualise your old machine to your new one.

Alternatively, if you plonk your old drive in the new one, it will automatically be detected - you can always boot from your main drive and just get the data from the temp drive.

If you reformat/reinstall Windows on the old drive whilst preserving the data, there will be no benefit over just copying your data from the drive.

Comment: Hi William thanks for the prompt reply, you´ve kind of verified what i was thinking, looks like im going to have a tedious day...